# What is the difference between CLDC and MIDP for Java Mobile?

Tags: java-me, midp, cldc

Could anyone explain what the difference is between CLDC and MIDP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java Mobile Edition has [two different components](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/getstart/articles/survey/).

The first, configuration, is the JVM and the core classes for running a virtual machine such as IO, collection classes, dates, strings, ext. CLDC is a configuration

The other, profile, contains classes for that are more utilities that are built on top of this, such as UI, encryption, persisting local data, ect. MIDP is a profile

Comment: You could theorically run a different Profile on top of CLDC. Also, CLDC alone doesn't let you display anything on the mobile phone screen.

Answer (score 2):

J2ME technology is made up of two configurations: the Connected Limited Device Configuration(CLDC) and the Connected Device Configuration(CDC).

Connected Limited Device Configuration (CLDC) is for devices with very constrained resources, like 160-512 KB of memory, limited bandwidth connectivity and 16-bit or 32-bit processor. CLDC does not supports full featured Java virtual machine. It does not supports floating point numbers, Thread groups, Object finalization, JNI, reflection, User class loaders.
Connected Device Configuration (CDC) is for devices with 2MB or more for Java platform, high bandwidth network connectivity and 32-bit processor. CDC supports a complete, full featured Java virtual machine.